# I just polyurethane 700 sq ft. of hardwood flooring

Tags: hardwood

[image: Newly Poly'd Floor]I waited 48 hours for the floor to cure, got on it with knee pads and left impressions. Some slid and wrinkled. How do I repair these spots. I have about 7 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Oil based? 48 hours should have been plenty of time. You sure it's not water-based?

Either way, give it another day or so. Rub out the sins with some 220 by hand, making sure to feather it out. Re-poly just the affected board (s).

If that doesn't fly, I know you don't want to hear it, but recoat the whole floor.

Comment: Do i cut the wrinkled divits out first?

Comment: It is water based.

Comment: No, don't cut, only sand. Cutting will cause hard lines. Waterbased can be a real pain if it doesn't do right the first time. If it isn't dry after 48 hours, chances are the stain underneath wasn't dry enough for the waterbased finish. Sometimes takes up to 10 days before clear can be installed.

Comment: Please forgive me. I just read the can. It is indeed oil based.

Comment: That's great news! Repairs should be easy, in that case.

Comment: It has 3 coats but only the top coat is effected.

Comment: Do I use polyurethane or just urethane to fill in the divits,

Comment: Since you are using oil-base, you can use almost anything. I've actually used 2-part 5 minute epoxy to fill empty knotholes. In your case, using poly should do the trick.